# Word, Regex for brackets, word, whitespace or lf

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

In Word, I would like to use the regular expressions to match "Po" followed by either a whitespace or end of line character.

```
[[Policy.PolicyNumber]]
[[Po
[[Po John
```

So in the above example I would like to match the bottom two items - "[[Po" and "[[Po" (*without the John*).

Ultimately what I am doing is an Intellisense - kind of VSTO.  I can search through the text of the document to find what I am after with c# using real regular expressions, but where I hit the snag point is making the replacement and not losing any formatting.  Hence using the .Replace word method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed this solution on Word for Mac. Go to `Edit->Find->Advanced Find and Replace`. Pull up the advanced options, and select the `Use wildcards` checkbox.

Search on this: `\[\[Po[^013 ]`

The ^013 is the code for a carriage return.